# (React) updating css attribute of referenced component without changing style of original

Tags: css, reactjs

In React, if I am using an existing, custom component in my component and want to edit the imported/referenced component's css attribute without changing the actual component's styling, how can I do that ?

I am doing this using useRef inside useEffect() but I think this is unsafe and repetitious/inefficient (even though it gives me the result I want). Is there another or better solution?

Some points to note:

- code between **asterisks** are my addition to the component that is in question
- 'icon-column' is an attribute defined in CustomComponent's css
- I am trying to edit CustomComponent's 'icon-column' attribute without actually changing it in the original css.
- 'custon-icon-column' attribute will be defined (replace 'icon-column) in myConponent.css

Here is my current code:

```
const myComponent = () => {
    **const componentRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
       //remove current styling
       componentRef.current.classList.remove('icon-column'); 
       
      //add my custom styling
      componentRef.current.classList.add('custom-icon-column');  

    }, []);**

    return(
      <div className = {styles.cardAStyle}>
      <CustomComponent
         border  
         icon = {iconName}
         title = {'Some title'}
         **ref = {componentRef}**
      >
      <Button/>
      </CustomComponent>
      </div>
      <div className = {styles.cardBStyle}>
      <CustomComponent
         border  
         icon = {iconName}
         title = {'Some title'}
         **ref = {componentRef}**
      >
      <Button/>
      </CustomComponent>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components)

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledCustomComponent = styled(CustomComponent)`
    &.icon-column {
        // override current icon-column
    }
`;

const MyComponent = () => {
    return(
        <div className={styles.cardAStyle}>
            <StyledCustomComponent
                border  
                icon={iconName}
                title={'Some title'}
                className='custom-icon-column'
            >
                <Button/>
            </StyledCustomComponent>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.cardBStyle}>
            <StyledCustomComponent
                border  
                icon={iconName}
                title={'Some title'}
                className='custom-icon-column'
            >
                <Button/>
            </StyledCustomComponent>
        </div>
    )
}
```